# convert list model to another list model based on same id

Tags: c#, list, data-conversion

I have below list with below model

```
public class Participant{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}
```

Input

```
Id Name    Adress
1  Jhon    America
2  Jhon    Indonesia 
3  Jhon    Jerman
4  Okto    Africa
4  Okto    Arabic
5  Syahrul India
```

How can I convert that list into below model based on id

```
public class Participant{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public List<Address> Address{ get; set; }
}

public class Address{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

So the result will be like this

```
Id Name    Adress
1  Jhon    America,Indonesia,Jerman 
4  OKTO    ARABIC,Africa
5  Syahrul India
```

my approach is i will use for loop and when the id is same i will add the addresss
if then skip to next id

but i failed to do that

is there any good and efficient way to do that

Comment: "How can I convert that list into below model based on id" sorry but the posted expected result is not based on Id, Why do the 3 different `Jhon`'s with 3 different Id's have the same Id `1` in the result? and why did `Okto` disapear? and is now called `Africa`? very confusing mate ;)

Comment: I think we see what you mean, but please take care to ensure that your expected output is accurate. You can edit your question

Comment: thank you for the edit, but my first point remains. Please explain how this result: `1  Jhon    America,Indonesia,Jerman ` is supposed to come about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the `Id` and `Name`. Then you need to select from each group an entity of your new model. The Id and Name you can get from the grouping key and the addresses have to be selected on their own:

```
List<Participant_New> newModelCollection = participantCollection
                    .GroupBy(x => new {Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name})
                    .Select(g => new Participant_New
                    {
                        Id = g.Key.Id,
                        Name = g.Key.Name,
                        Address = g.Select(a => new Address{Name = a.Address}).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a less heavy Linq solution you can do something like the following.

```cs
List<Participant> participants = new List<Participant>();
List<Participant2> participant2s = new List<Participant2>();

foreach (var participant in participants)
{
    Participant2 par = participant2s.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == participant.Id);

    if (par is null)
    {
        participant2s.Add(new Participant2
        {
            Id = participant.Id,
            Name = participant.Name,
            Adresses = new List<Address> { new Address { Name = participant.Address } }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        par.Adresses.Add(new Address { Name = participant.Address });
    }
}
```

#### Notes

You might prefer this solution over others, since at least IMO it is easier to read. Also if you are getting more complex this would be even more readable.

#### Explanation

1. It is fairly simple, you create a new List of your new Model in this case `Participant2`.
2. After that you just loop through all entries in your first list containing the 'old' models.
3. You check if you already have an entry in your List containing an item with the same Id.
4. If there is **no** match, it will just create a new item containing the same information.
5. If there is **a** match, it will add the Address to the entry.

#### Important Information

If one of those Lists is a `DbSet<T>` or similar you should be very careful, since this code won't get executed on the Database itself, which can really hurt the performance.

Comment: what do u think about effeciency with @mongzhu answer

Comment: Well it is just fine as well, but you can always test both of these methods with a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` and see if there is any difference.